# How to do a backup of files using the terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, backup

I've already done a backup of my database, using mysqldump like this:

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u dbUsername -p dbDatabase > backup.sql
```

After that the file is in a location outside public access, in my server, ready for download.

How may I do something like that for files? I've tried to google it, but I get all kind of results, but that.

I need to tell the server running ubuntu to backup all files inside folder X, and put them into a zip file.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say I'm using ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tar for creating backups for a full system backup

```
tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz  /
```

for a single folder

```
    tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz  /your/folder
```

to create a gzipped tar file of your whole system. You might need additional excludes like 
 `--exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys --exclude=/dev/pts`.

If you are outside of the single folder you want to backup the `--exclude=/backup.tar.gz` isn't needed.

More details for example [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR) (you can do it over network, split the archive etc.).